Shibboleth IdP metadata XML: Unable to open directory
Shibboleth is having issues reading/writing where it needs to do stuff.  I'm using Shibboleth 3.4 SP installed on Windows Server 2022 with IIS 10.
I'm running this command to check the setup:
C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\sbin64\shibd.exe -check 
I've set Shibboleth to have local IdP metadata XML file, but I'm getting an error:
2024-04-19 08:43:09 WARN Shibboleth.DEPRECATION : MetadataGenerator handler
2024-04-19 08:43:09 WARN OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.Folder : Unable to open directory (C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/<foo2>.xml)
overall configuration is loadable, check console or log for non-fatal problems

Huh, doesn't work.  Maybe it's a permission thing? Let's give 'Everyone' 'Full Control' permission on the root shibboleth directory:
2024-04-19 08:46:47 WARN Shibboleth.DEPRECATION : MetadataGenerator handler
2024-04-19 08:46:47 WARN OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.Folder : Unable to open directory (C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/<foo2>.xml)
overall configuration is loadable, check console or log for non-fatal problems

Nope, that didn't change anything.  Here's the output from the shibd_warn.log:
2024-04-19 08:46:41 WARN Shibboleth.DEPRECATION : MetadataGenerator handler
2024-04-19 08:46:41 WARN OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.Folder : Unable to open directory (C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/<foo2>.xml)

Here's the 'juicy' part of the shibd.log:
2024-04-19 08:46:41 WARN Shibboleth.DEPRECATION : MetadataGenerator handler
2024-04-19 08:46:41 INFO Shibboleth.Handler.DiscoveryFeed : feed files will be cached in C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/var/cache/shibboleth/
2024-04-19 08:46:41 INFO Shibboleth.Application : building MetadataProvider of type Folder...
2024-04-19 08:46:41 INFO OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.Folder : loading metadata files from folder (C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/<foo2>.xml)
2024-04-19 08:46:41 WARN OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.Folder : Unable to open directory (C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/<foo2>.xml)

Here's the IdP metadata part of the shibboleth2.xml:
<MetadataProvider type="Folder" validate="true" path="<foo2>.xml" />
I've ran the 'Repair', uninstalled and reinstalled Shibboleth, and added the root file as an antivirus exception for scanning to no avail.
update: commented out the <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" in the shibbleth2.xml to get rid of the WARN Shibboleth.DEPRECATION : MetadataGenerator handler red herring.
